# State of a thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I got a question like what is the state of a thread when it is created. And the option has both ready and runnable. So my doubts are,

1. Is there any state called ready state?
2. If so then, is there any difference between runnable and ready state of a thread?
3. If so then, what will be the appropiate answer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not an *exact* duplicate.. Voting to *reopen*.

Comment: You can answer your questions by (a) looking at the Javadoc for java.lang.Thread, and (b) writing a program that you can run to see what it actually does.

Answer (score 2):

1 - no, it's NEW

2 - NEW is waiting to be executed, RUNNABLE is executing

3 - NEW

Who could answer better than Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is java's thread state automat:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually *starting* and *executing* a thread involves collaboration between the JVM and the OS. The JVM makes a call to the underlying OS. The states you mention like *ready* is the state when the Thread is in the *waiting Threads set*. This means that the Thread is *ready for execution* and the Thread scheduler can schedule it.

Don't mix up OS and Java level states. From Java's perspective there are only 5 states

```
1. New
2. Runnable
3. Waiting
4. Timed Waiting
5. Terminated
```

Comment: Wait and blocked are two different states.

Comment: @Mikhail -  *Blocked* can be considered as *Timed Waiting / Waiting*.

Comment: Waiting state has nothing to do with timed waiting. In the first case monitors are released. Thread could be blocked because of IO, not only monitor entering. These are three different states. May be a bit similar in some way, but no more.

Comment: @Mikhail - If your Thread is *blocked*, then it is *waiting*. If your program or internally the OS calls `sleep()`, then the thread will be blocked. You can wait for a specific amount of time or you can wait for an interrupt / to be notified. Thus, the waiting can be either timed or not based on time.

Answer (score 1):

you can find answer at VM.java,there are six state

```
public static Thread.State toThreadState(int threadStatus) {
    if ((threadStatus & JVMTI_THREAD_STATE_RUNNABLE) != 0) {
        return RUNNABLE;
    } else if ((threadStatus & JVMTI_THREAD_STATE_BLOCKED_ON_MONITOR_ENTER) != 0) {
        return BLOCKED;
    } else if ((threadStatus & JVMTI_THREAD_STATE_WAITING_INDEFINITELY) != 0) {
        return WAITING;
    } else if ((threadStatus & JVMTI_THREAD_STATE_WAITING_WITH_TIMEOUT) != 0) {
        return TIMED_WAITING;
    } else if ((threadStatus & JVMTI_THREAD_STATE_TERMINATED) != 0) {
        return TERMINATED;
    } else if ((threadStatus & JVMTI_THREAD_STATE_ALIVE) == 0) {
        return NEW;
    } else {
        return RUNNABLE;
    }
}
```